# Most efficient multiple "loop" in MatLab

Tags: matlab, loops

I want to make multiple simulations of a statistical process that depend on two arguments. I want to simulate for multiple combinations of those arguments. I am trying different approaches but or I end up with too many vectors or with just the last vector that it was looped.

For the sake of simplicity, my example of statistical process will be an AR(1) that depends on `rho` and `sigma`.

I will post two codes:

- The first is wrong (because it only saves the last realization of
  my loop) but I think it is telling in showing what I am trying to do
- The second works but it is "too long" and not very professional

**FIRST CODE: wrong, but telling**

```
%Parameters and random walk process
rho=linspace(0.1,0.9,5);
sigma=linspace(0.1,1,5)';
T=100;
epsilon=randn(T+1,1); 

%Interval for rhos and sigmas
rho_step=(rho(3)-rho(1))/3
sigma_step=(sigma(3)-sigma(1))/3


for rho=0.1:rho_step:0.95
    for sigma=0.001:sigma_step:0.4
        y=ones(T+1,1);  
        for i=2:T
     y(i)=exp(rho*log(y(i-1))+sigma*epsilon(i));
        end
    end
end
```

**SECOND CODE: works, but doesn't look efficient**

```
%Parameters and random walk process
rho=linspace(0.1,0.9,5);
sigma=linspace(0.1,1,5)';
T=100;
epsilon=randn(T+1,1); 

%Interval for rhos and sigmas
rho_step=(rho(3)-rho(1))/5
sigma_step=(sigma(3)-sigma(1))/5

i=1;
for rho=0.1:rho_step:0.95
    r(1,i)=rho;
    j=1;
    for sigma=0.001:sigma_step:0.4
        s(j,1)=sigma;
        y=ones(T+1,1);  
        for k=2:T
            y(k)=exp(rho*log(y(k-1))+sigma*epsilon(k));
        end
        if i==1
            s1(:,j)=y;
        elseif i==2
            s2(:,j)=y;
        elseif i==3
            s3(:,j)=y;
        elseif i==4
            s4(:,j)=y;
        elseif i==5
            s5(:,j)=y;
        end
        j=j+1;

    end
    i=i+1;
end
```

Anyone with a more efficient way of doing this? I am looking forward for tips :)

Comment: One thought would be to add a 3D array (e.g. `x(:,j,i)`) rather than using `s1, s2, s3, ...` so you don't need the `if/elseif` chain. I don't know if it'll add a significant speed increase but it's certainly cleaner.

Comment: Of course! I need to solve this 2D mind I have for coding! Thank you very much, @excaza! Do you want to show your suggestion below so I can vote?

Comment: You're welcome :) It was really just a tip, like I said it may not have an appreciable impact on the speed of your function. I'll defer to those who have a better handle on the calculations being done and whether or not they can be done in a more vectorized manner rather than with individual iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do a gridsearch over all combinations of `rho` and `sigma`, which then yield a different `y`?

In this case I'd suggest the use of `combvec`. The nice thing is that this code generalizes easy to combinations of more parameters ifneedbe (But beware of the combinatorial explosion ;)).

```
%Param Init
rho=linspace(0.1,0.9,5);
sigma=linspace(0.1,1,5)';
T=100;
epsilon=randn(T+1,1); 

rho_step=(rho(3)-rho(1))/5
sigma_step=(sigma(3)-sigma(1))/5

k=2:T;

rhos=0.1:rho_step:0.95;
sigmas=0.001:sigma_step:0.4;


%generate all combinations of input vectors:
V = combvec(rhos,sigmas); 

res = [];


%gridsearch
for i = 1:size(V,2);
    y=ones(T+1,1);

    rho = V(1,i);
    sigma = V(2,i);
    for k=2:T
        y(k) = exp(rho*log(y(k-1))+sigma*epsilon(k));
    end

    %store result along with parameters
    res(i).y = y;
    res(i).rho = rho;
    res(i).sigma = sigma;

end
```

Best,
Dominic

Comment: Hi @Dominic. It seems like a very cool suggestion but I don't have the Neural Network Toolbox™ :)

Answer (score 0):

Following @excaza 's suggestion, let's use the same initialization than before for parameters and intervals, but let's have a 3D result instead of long loops:

```
for j=1:5
    for i=1:5
        y=ones(T+1,j,i);  
        for k=2:T
            y(k,j,i)=exp(rho(j)*log(y(k-1,j,i))+sigma(i)*epsilon(k));
        end
    end
end
```